# Is it possible to set const using a user-input?

Tags: c, constants, user-input

When programming in C, is it possible to set a `const` with a value of a user-input?
If so, how?

Comment: No. If it was it wouldn't be a `const` would it. Perhaps if you describe the problem you are trying to solve, rather than the (impossible) solution you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not?

```
void some_function(int user_input)
{
    const int const_user_input = user_input;
    ...
    return;
}

int main (void)
{
    int user_input;
    scanf("%d", &user_input);
    some_function(user_input);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

you can have that even more directly than in Dadam's answer. (Normally I would have put just in a comment, but it is easier to put that in code directly.)

```
int get_user_input(void)
{
    int user_input;
    scanf("%d", &user_input);
    return user_input;
}

int main(void)
{
    int const user_input = get_user_input();
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf("enter your number : ");
   const int i = scanf("%d",&i)*i;
   printf("%d",i);
}
```

let me explain how this code works.
first you should know the point that `scanf()` function returns an `integer` value equal to the no of items it read from the user.

for example:

1) `scanf("%d",&a);` this statement returns value 1 since it read only one item.

2) `scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);` this statement returns value 2 since it read two integers `a` and `b`.

similarly when we assigned `scanf("%d",&i)*i` to `i` it gives the value one multiplied by the value of `i`(which we given as input). therefore you get the same value of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Linker usually locate global const in read-only space (like code space) and therefore it cannot be changed later on

See comments on local const

Comment: Not always true: A local variable can be const, and initialized by a run-time value, at least in C99 and many C89 variants.

Comment: @JohanBezem OP never mentioned scope, so it's best to err on the side of caution and say no.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers (which all say no), you could do some ugly things like

```
static const int notsoconst = 3;
scanf("%d", ((int*) &notsoconst));
```

But this could compile, but it probably would crash at runtime (and is  [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in the C language specification), because `notsoconst` would be put in a read-only segment (at least with GCC on Linux).

Even if it is doable, I don't recommend coding this way. And even if your implementation does not put constants in some read-only segment, the compiler is allowed to expect `const` to never change (as specified in the language standard) and is allowed to optimize with this assumption.

Comment: It's definitely undefined behavior (6.7.3/5: "If an attempt is made to modify an object deﬁned with a const-qualiﬁed type through use
of an lvalue with non-const-qualiﬁed type, the behavior is undeﬁned.")

Answer (score -2):

A const variable is C is technically read only. So one can't set it from user-input